# Selection of method overloading with super-class instance in Java

Tags: java, overloading

Let's say I have two classes as follows.

```
class Animal {}

class Dog extends Animal {}

class Cat extends Animal {}
```

In another class, I am doing method overloading with different arguments.

```
// method 1
public void doSomething(Dog dog) {
// do something
}

// method 2
public void doSomething(Animal animal) {
// do something
}
```

Now what I want to know is when I call `doSomthing` method with `Cat` instance, does it call the method 2 or throws an error?

```
Cat cat = new Cat();
this.doSOmething(cat);
```

Answer (score 0):

It would call the overloaded method that takes the `Animal` type argument because `Cat` extends from `Animal`:

```
public void doSomething(Animal animal) { ... }
```